# Stripping out partial path name

Tags: dos

hoping somebody can help.
I'm working in DOS (windows 7 if it matters), and have got the following little snippet of code:

```
@ECHO OFF

echo x:\junk\main\something\file1.txt     > temp.txt
echo x:\junk\main\something\file2.txt     >> temp.txt
echo x:\junk\main\else\file3.txt          >> temp.txt

set TMP=temp.txt

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

  for /F %%I IN (%TMP%) DO (
     echo File is: %%I

     set CFile=%%I
     set CFile=%CFile:~13%
     echo File really is: %CFile%
  )
```

Running this, generates the following results:

```
C:\temp>test
File is: x:\junk\main\something\file1.txt
File really is:
File is: x:\junk\main\something\file2.txt
File really is:
File is: x:\junk\main\else\file3.txt
File really is:

C:\temp>
```

So .. what am i doing wrong? why is it not keeping the value into CFile variable?
It seems to have something to do with either the FOR loop, or with the %%I syntax (opposed to %I%), but I'm not sure why??

Answer (score 0):

You are using delayed command line expansion, so you need to the `!` character in certain places instead of `%`.

```
@ECHO OFF

echo x:\junk\main\something\file1.txt     > temp.txt
echo x:\junk\main\something\file2.txt     >> temp.txt
echo x:\junk\main\else\file3.txt          >> temp.txt

set TMP=temp.txt

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F %%I IN (%TMP%) DO (
   echo File is: %%I

   set CFile=%%I
   set CFile=!CFile:~13!
   echo File really is: !CFile!
   echo.
   set CRealFile=%%~nxI
   echo The filename is: !CRealFile!
)
```

Although, I'm not sure that you really want to use `!CFile:~13!`.  The modified code above doesn't lose the `CFile` value anymore, but it doesn't look quite right.  I added a few lines to demonstration how to extract the filename from `%%I` as `!CRealFile!`.